# Clear a text file prior to Load in Java Servlet

Tags: java, servlets

I am not certain as to what I am doing wrong, and I am getting flustered

Here is my file "customer3.txt", it exists, I want to clear it and repopulate it with data from another file. It keep appending to the end, I have tried to use, I am using TRUE on my FileWriter so I don't understand what is going on.

here is the code snippets:

```
String path = sc.getRealPath("/");


File ftemp = new File(path + "/customer3.txt");
ftemp.delete();
File fcust = new File(path + "/customer3.txt");
fcust.createNewFile();

     PrintWriter outp = new PrintWriter(new BufferedWriter(new FileWriter(path + "/customer3.txt", true)));


         outp.print(id);
         outp.print(',');
         outp.print(name);  
         outp.print(',');
         outp.print(addr1);
         outp.print(',');
         outp.print(addr2);
         outp.print(',');
         outp.print(city);
         outp.print(',');
         outp.print(state);
         outp.print(',');
         outp.print(zip);
         outp.print(',');
         outp.print(phone);
         outp.print(',');
         outp.print(tvplan);
         outp.print(',');
         outp.print(intplan);
         outp.println();
         // Create record
         outp.flush();
         outp.close();
```

when I use append false ... it writes to the last line of the file

This cannot be this difficult.

one more thing, is there something I need to do to release the file from the Apache, it seems to lock up every so often.

Thank you for any help.

Answer (score 1):

Change this

```
new FileWriter(path + "/customer3.txt", true)
```

for this

```
new FileWriter(ftemp)
```

Explanation:

From 
[`FileWriter(File file, boolean append)`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/io/FileWriter.html#FileWriter%28java.io.File,%20boolean%29), the second parameter asks if new contents should be appended at the end of the file. Just let the Java API to handle the file recreation.